# Spanish accents don't show properly in chapter title

Tags: pdftex, books, spanish

I am using the Alon book template from Taylor and Francis. I am writing the text in Spanish. Inside the body of the text there are no problem with spanish accents using `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`.

However, the chapter title and doesn't show the spanish accents properly:

[image]

Here's the code:

```
    \documentclass[Alon1, singlecolor,ChapterTOCs, twoside, final, 12pt, openright, letterpaper, titlepage]{Alon}
\usepackage{fixltx2e,fix-cm}

\usepackage{todonotes}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}% fancyhdr related command; details in its documentation

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[object=vectorian]{pgfornament}

\usepackage[letterpaper,
top=0.5in,
left=1in,
right=1.2in,
bottom=1.2in, footskip=1.25cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xstring}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chtocnamefont \thechapter.\ \protect\StrLeft{#1}{65}...}{}}

\frenchspacing
\tolerance=5000

\makeindex

\title{Título}
\author{Autores}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\halftitle
\maketitle%This is a placeholder titlepage, it will not be final.

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{7} %previous pages reserved for frontmatter to be added later

% Solo pone en la tabla de contenidos los titulos de los capitulos
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\include{chapters/chapter1/ch2}

\backmatter

\end{document}
```

The code for ch2.tex:

```
\chapterauthor{Fernández, Alexander}{}

\chapter{Innovación para la transformación}
    
    \section{Introducción}

    \chapterinitial{E}{N} este prólogo no me adentraré en los contenidos que el libro propone. Los lectores podrán evaluarlos y encontrar en ellos elementos de interés. Más bien deseo aprovechar la oportunidad para enfatizar algunos cambios que se han producido en la dinámica del desarrollo local en el país desde 2018 a la fecha.

    \begin{center}
        \pgfornament[height=.3\baselineskip]{88}
    \end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a standard class? We don't have access to your template, after all. That said, there are many packages in your template that probably have nothing at all to do with the issue at hand. Try to reduce your example as much as possible.

Comment: The `Alon` document class does not appear to be part of the standard TeX distributions; is its code available online somewhere? A separate thought: Does adding the instruction `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` in the preamble help?